# pandas Dataframe how to filter with Date as index

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to filter DataFrame by using datetime as index . 
I put this code :

```
filt = (confirmed_df.index > '3/19/20')
```

`confirmed_df.loc[filt]`

and the result shows again rows which are before  '3/19/20'

[image]

do you know what's wrong with this code ?

Answer (score 0):

I think here is necessary create `DatetimeIndex` first:

```
confirmed_df.index = pd.to_datetime(confirmed_df.index, format='%m/%d/%y')
```

And then filter by string in format `YYYY-MM-DD`:

```
filt = (confirmed_df.index > '2020-03-19')
```